# While loops and nested if do not work together

Tags: c, loops, nested

When there is no while loop, the code runs fine. Because İt has not worked which the last else on the nested if. The statemen is "invalid character".But as it is below, it does not work. Where is the error? I tried to remove the while loops. And it ran. But so in this manner, it doesn't work. In my opinion, this situation is a specific condition of the while loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   unsigned int aCount = 0; 
   unsigned int bCount = 0; 
   unsigned int cCount = 0; 
   unsigned int dCount = 0;
   unsigned int fCount = 0; 

   puts("Enter the letter grades." );
   puts("Enter the EOF character to end input." );
   int grade; // one grade 

   // loop until user types end-of-file key sequence
    while (( grade = getchar()) != EOF) { //while

        if(grade == 'A'|| grade == 'a')
        {
            ++aCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'B' || grade == 'b')
        {
            ++bCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'C' || grade == 'c')
        {
            ++cCount;
        }
        else if(grade =='D' || grade == 'd')
        {
            ++dCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'F' || grade =='f')
        {
            ++fCount;
        }
        else
        {
            puts("invalid character");

        }

   }//while





   // output summary of results
   puts("\nTotals for each letter grade are:");
   printf("A: %u\n", aCount);
   printf("B: %u\n", bCount); 
   printf("C: %u\n", cCount); 
   printf("D: %u\n", dCount); 
   printf("F: %u\n", fCount); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes they do. What doesn't work?

Comment: What exactly does "it do not works" mean?  *How* do you know it doesn't work?  What is the expected and actual output of the program?

Comment: A tip for optimization - have a `int count[5]` array and then increment `count[tolower(grade) - 'a']`.

Comment: Suggestion: Use `grade = tolower(grade)` so you only have to compare with one character instead of both uppercase and lowercase.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You mean `count[6]`. The last grade is F, not E.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, missed the fact there is no `e`... Not used to this grading system :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with using `if` inside `while.

As a comment mentioned, space and newline characters between the grades will cause it to print "Invalid character". You should just ignore those characters rather than printing a message.

The loop will end when the user types the EOF character at the beginning of a line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
   unsigned int aCount = 0; 
   unsigned int bCount = 0; 
   unsigned int cCount = 0; 
   unsigned int dCount = 0;
   unsigned int fCount = 0; 

   puts("Enter the letter grades." );
   puts("Enter the EOF character to end input." );
   int grade; // one grade 

   // loop until user types end-of-file key sequence
    while (( grade = getchar()) != EOF) { //while
        grade = tolower(grade);
        if(grade == 'a')
        {
            ++aCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'b')
        {
            ++bCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'c')
        {
            ++cCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'd')
        {
            ++dCount;
        }
        else if(grade =='f')
        {
            ++fCount;
        }
        else if (isspace(grade)) {
            // ignore whitespace
        }
        else
        {
            printf("invalid character '%c'\n", grade);
        }

   }//while

   // output summary of results
   puts("\nTotals for each letter grade are:\n");
   printf("A: %u\n", aCount);
   printf("B: %u\n", bCount); 
   printf("C: %u\n", cCount); 
   printf("D: %u\n", dCount); 
   printf("F: %u\n", fCount); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot. i understood it. Yeah. for example i write 'a' then i press enter. En enter is  == \n. Now its true.

Answer (score 0):

'\n' also counts as a character,and so does ' ' .All in all you never check for those character.
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   unsigned int aCount = 0; 
   unsigned int bCount = 0; 
   unsigned int cCount = 0; 
   unsigned int dCount = 0;
   unsigned int fCount = 0; 

   puts("Enter the letter grades." );
   puts("Enter the EOF character to end input." );
   int grade; 


    while (( grade = getchar()) != EOF  ) { 

        if(grade == 'A'|| grade == 'a')
        {
            ++aCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'B' || grade == 'b')
        {
            ++bCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'C' || grade == 'c')
        {
            ++cCount;
        }
        else if(grade =='D' || grade == 'd')
        {
            ++dCount;
        }
        else if(grade == 'F' || grade =='f')
        {
            ++fCount;
        }
        else if(grade =='\n' || grade==' ')
        {
            continue;

        }
        else
        {
        puts("invalid character");
        }
   }


   puts("\nTotals for each letter grade are:");
   printf("A: %u\n", aCount);
   printf("B: %u\n", bCount); 
   printf("C: %u\n", cCount); 
   printf("D: %u\n", dCount); 
   printf("F: %u\n", fCount); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The prompt says that it ends with EOF, not newline.